# Trying to join separate open paths into one closed shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pathfinder, fill

I've created a cloud shape using the pen tool, and it's made up of separate, unclosed paths.  All of the anchor points are connected to each other, but because the ends of some of the paths are open I can't seem to use any of the normal ways I've used in the past to make it one shape like pathfinder, join, etc.

I just need it to be recognised as a closed shape with internal open lines so I can fill it.

[image: the shape I need to close]

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Live Paint group](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/live-paint-groups.html).

It looks like you have a brush applied to your stroke; Live Paint will remove your brush stroke so group your artwork and duplicate it first (one to use for the Live Paint group and one for the brush stroke). Or you can use a regular stroke with no brush or outline your stroke first...

Click the Live Paint Bucket (<kbd>K</kbd>) on the artwork to create a Live Paint group...

[image]

Once you've created the Live Paint group it's as simple as clicking and choosing a color and removing the stroke...

[image]

Unhide your layer with the brush strokes on top...

[image]